# importing CA certs into OpenSSL CLI

Tags: openssl

I created a CA cert and a cert signed by the CA cert and then tried to sign a CMS / PKCS7 message with the CA-signed cert and got the following error:

```
unable to get local issuer certificate
```

I.e. it sounds like I need to import the CA cert I created into OpenSSL somehow. Any ideas as to how I'd go about doing that?

Comment: You put the right files in the right places, where "right" is OS and sometimes environment dependent.  Have you tried [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=openssl%20import%20trusted%20root%20certificate&rct=j)?

Answer (score 1):

OpenSSL issues this error because the root cert is not in the location that it is expects it. The default directory for this (tested only my debian wheezy machine) is  `/etc/ssl/certs`.

Hope this helps.